# Tools for converting recovery phrase?

Tags: wallet-recovery, mycelium-wallet, breadwallet

I have a wallet on Breadwallet which I wish to move to Mycelium. Both apps support recovery phrases, however Breadwallet uses BIP39 phrases, while Mycelium uses BIP44 phrases. Is it possible to convert from one format to the other, and if so, could you point me to any tools that can do this?

Comment: This seems confused. There is no such thing as a BIP44 phrase, as BIP44 is just a standard for deriving keys from a master key.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://coinomi.com/recovery-phrase-tool.html
Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I had come across this before, but I could not see a way to produce a bip44 recovery phrase from a bip39 one?